# Selenium IDE - Verify Value for class

Tags: css, class, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I want to verify the value of specific class in `HTML` code with `Selenium IDE`, In the next code I want to get the value of: `data-val` that under class called `tgl`, in my example it can be `0` or `1`. 
how can I do it with `Selenium IDE`? How can I verify that the value is `0` or `1`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <body id="rpt-page-control-wafd" data-dir="ltr" data-lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nav" style="background-color: transparent;">
  <div id="page-ext">
  <div id="page-content">
  <div id="page-main" class="module module-simple" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:1008px;height:532px;display:;">
     <div id="wafd-t" class="cont cont-full" style="left: 0px; top: 91px; width: 1008px; height: 441px; background-color: transparent;">
        <div class="cont-grid cont-grid-extended-header">
           <table id="wafd-t-tblh" class="data-grid data-grid-header" style="background-color: transparent;">
           <table id="wafd-t-tblb" class="data-grid data-grid-body" style="background-color: transparent;">
              <tbody>
                 <tr class="" data-row="1">
                    <td class="col-idx" style="width:72px;" data-max="999.0" data-min="0.0" data-val="1" data-col="CONTROL_WATER_AND_FEED__Day">
                    <td class="hour editable" style="width:80px;" data-max="1440.0" data-min="0.0" data-val="01:01" data-col="CONTROL_WATER_AND_FEED__Time">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width: 60px; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);" data-val="0" data-col="water_1">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width: 60px; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);" data-val="0" data-col="water_2">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width: 60px; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);" data-val="1" data-col="water_3">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="water_4">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="feed_1">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="1" data-col="feed_2">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="feed_3">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="feed_4">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="auger_1">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="auger_2">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="auger_3">
                    <td class="tgl" style="width:60px;" data-val="0" data-col="auger_4">
                    <td class="col-edit" style="width:72px;" data-col="col_edit">
                 </tr>
                 <tr data-row="2">
                 <tr data-row="3">
                 <tr data-row="4">
                 <tr data-row="5">
                 <tr data-row="6">
                 <tr data-row="7">
              </tbody>
           </table>
           <table id="wafd-t-tbl" class="data-grid" style="display: none;"></table>
           <div id="wafd-t-tbl-vscroll" class="data-grid-vscroller" style="top: 64px; height: 330px; width: 872px; background-color: transparent;"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="wafd-s" class="cont cont-modal" style="left:8px;top:20px;width:992px;height:470px;display:none;">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="page-float-ext" style="display:none;">
  </div>
  <script src="js/common.js?v11">
  <script src="js/plugins/plugin.numkeypad.js?v11">
  <script src="js/plugins/plugin.timekeypad.js?v11">
  <script src="js/plugins/plugin.passcodepanel.js?v11">
  <script src="js/plugins/plugin.datagrid.js?v11">
  <script src="js/plugins/plugin.settingspanel.js?v11">
  <script src="js/plugins/plugin.helppanel.js?v11">
  <script src="js/ESLNS/JSGlobals.js?v11">
  <script src="js/ESLNS/DataServiceUtils.js?v11">
  <script src="js/ESLNS/DataConverts.js?v11">
  <script src="js/libs/moment.min.js">
  <script src="js/page.control-wafd.js">
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
  <script src="js/libs/highcharts.js">
  <script src="js/libs/highcharts-more.js">
  <script src="js/libs/yepnope.1.5.4-min.js">
  <script src="js/libs/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js">
  <script src="js/main.js">
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "verify the value of specific class in HTML"?

Comment: If the value is "1" the step is pass if it "0" it will failed

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `javascript` to accomplish this. `runScriptAndWait` command allows you to verify the attribute value against a `tag`. You just have to be careful about writing the script

`runScriptAndWait`|`document.querySelector("data-col='CONTROL_WATER_AND_FEED__Day'").getAttribute("data-val")`|`1`

[image]