# Javascript one liner to make sure checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am working with selenium ide and was wondering if there is a one line that can make sure a checkbox is checked.

or any other selenium javascript commands you've used in the past would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all!!

Comment: Can you provide some `html`?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610501/selenium-ide-verify-value-for-class/28611318#28611318)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the value (read whether true or false): just add ".checked" to the end of the object that represents the checkbox, let's pretend our checkbox has an id="checkBox":

```
checkBox.checked  // returns true or false.
```

If you want to set the checked attribute to checked

```
checkBox.checked = true;
```

Looking at the link in the comment, it looks like you're using query selector. Unlike jQuery there's no built in each on the array like list returned by the querySelectorAll method...

In one line, it is messy...

To get:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function(checkbox){return checkbox.checked; });
```

To set

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function(checkbox){checkbox.checked = true; });
```

edit: Added return keyword to the "get" version.

edit2: a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/pLgjx4xa/